# Vectorize the cumulative sum of a column where the cumulative sum resets to zero each time a goal is reached?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, vectorization

I have a large dataframe DF and I am trying to determine each time the column value of the ith row pushes the cumulative tally of the column past a specific Goal. However,  the cumulative tally has to be reset back to zero each time the Goal is met.  I then wish to mask the data frame down to these specific rows.

So say...

```
Data={'Location':[1,2,3,5,7,4,6]}
DF= pd.DataFrame(Data)
DF['Points']=DF['Location'].diff()

Out:
   Location  Points
0         1     NaN
1         2     1.0
2         3     1.0
3         5     2.0
4         7     2.0
5         4    -3.0
6         6     2.0
```

I wanted to mask DF down to the rows where the distance from a starting point is greater than 2.  But each time the distance of two is reached the starting point resets.

In loop form the logic might look something like this.

```
def resetsum(): 
    L=[]    
    Points=0
    for i in range(len(DF)):
        Points += DF['Points'].iloc[i]
        if Points >= Goal:
           L.append(Df.iloc[i].index)
           Points = 0
```

I could then use L to mask DF.  However the dataset is incredibly large and it must be run multiple times so looping will take a very long time. Is there a way to vectorize this or modify a cumsum implementation so that it resets itself when a given threshold is met?

I have looked at rolling.sum in Pandas but that requires a fixed window.  In this case the window would be variable because I don't know how many rows back the Goal was previously reached.

Comment: If `Goal` is fixed, then you just need floor division to get something to group by

Comment: You should add more example data so we can answer your question better

Comment: Thanks I hope this makes the question more clear.  @roganjosh thanks.  would you be able to elaborate on your method a little further?